# Displaying json returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Basically I have a returned json object like this:

```
"products":[
    {
        "id": "21102165",
        "name": "Eliza J (3/4 sleeve ruched waist dress)",
    }]
```

My method to display it:

```
function getCart(){
var json = $.getJSON('https://'+storedomain+'/cart?'+fcc.session_get()+'&output=json&callback=?');
alert(json['name']);
}
```

However the alert displays "undefined". Where I'm I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.getJSON` return $.Deferred object and not a result

```
function getCart(){
    $.getJSON('https://'+storedomain+'/cart?'+fcc.session_get()+'&output=json&callback=?', function(data) {
        console.log(data.products[0].name);
    });
}
```

you can do:

```
function getCart(){
    return $.getJSON('https://'+storedomain+'/cart?'+fcc.session_get()+'&output=json&callback=?');
}  

$.when(getCart()).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.products[0].name);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by $.Deferred object?

Comment: You should also fix the other problem (data['name'] isn't going to work). But +1 from me for the main problem.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: @dystroy thank you for your suggestion for answer improving, hope it's ok now

Answer (score 0):

Use the success callback.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

See the API documentation for [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be:

```
function getCart(callback) {
    var url = 'https://'+storedomain + '/cart?'+fcc.session_get()+'&output=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, callback);
}

// Usage
getCart(function(data) {
    console.log(data.products); // array of car objects
});
```

Or you can use deffered object as explained in salexch answer.

You should become familiar with asynchronous nature of AJAX requests and with callback functions.